# Google Sheets formula to convert FROM ordinal dates TO standard dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking for a formula that will automatically convert a column of ordinal date/time values into standard date/time values.

```
July 1st 2022 6:48:49 pm
July 2nd 2022 10:03:35 am
July 3rd 2022 5:41:12 pm
July 4th 2022 2:44:13 pm
```

I need to get those reformatted to eliminate the st, nd, rd, and th portions.

[Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HPDCDfjBpwSetdGd6fmEk-g6w-1rB0n_06tAlhpYZFw/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A7="",, REGEXREPLACE(A2:A7,"st|nd|rd|th","")*1))
```

You can then format as you like

*(**Do** adjust the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

Functions used:

- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)